# How can I iterate throught array in loop and calculate dates between these with RN and Moment.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, foreach, momentjs

I am working on something with React Native Calendar. I need to get all the dates between two dates and marked these in React Native Calendar.
I have the start and the end date that are now in an array, I also can have the date between these but only if I specify with values I want from my array. The idea's that I want the function to get all the first/second / third and so on values and automatically calculate the date between these and finally marked these in my calendar. I can't have my all dates on this calendar actually.

How can I do that ? Thank you in advance here is my code :

```
    try {
        let res = await axios.get(`https://myseenapp.herokuapp.com/constructionSite/${_id}`);
        let data = res.data;
        setConstruction(data);

        setStartDate(
            data
                .map(e => e.startDate)
                .forEach((day) => {
                    let convert = day.split('-').reverse().join('-')
                    if (arrayStart.includes(convert) === false) {
                        arrayStart.push(convert)
                    }
                }));
        setEndDate(
            data
                .map(e => e.endDate)
                .forEach((day) => {
                    let convert = day.split('-').reverse().join('-')
                    if (arrayEnd.includes(convert) === false) {
                        arrayEnd.push(convert)
                    }
        }));
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
};

let end = moment(arrayEnd[0]);
let start = moment(arrayStart[0]);


const getDaysBetweenDates = (start, end) => {
    let now = start;
    let dates = [];
    while (now <= end){
        dates.push(now.format("YYYY-MM-DD"));
        now.add(1, 'days');
        dates.forEach((day) => {
            newDaysObject[day] = {
                textColor: "white",
                color: 'gold',
                selected: true,
            }
        })
    }
    return dates;
}
let dateList = getDaysBetweenDates(start, end);
console.log(dateList)
```

Comment: But your problem is calculate all dates? o insert this date in your calendar?

Comment: Hello, my problem is that I can not calculate all date by taking the first values of my startDate array and my EndDate array. It's working only if I specifies which value I want to take with my arrayEnd[0] & arrayStart[0] but not if I make a forEach.

Answer (score 0):

```
    const getDaysBetweenDates = (start, end) => {
        let now = start;
        let dates = [];
        while (now <= end){
            dates.push(now.format("YYYY-MM-DD"));
           now = momet(now).add(1, 'days'); // you are updating the same object again and again, so here I am creating new object
      
        }
     // moving this out so it runs only when all the dates are filled in array
// this should have been done outside this method for cleaner code

    dates.forEach((day) => { 
// not sure where this object came from.
                newDaysObject[day] = {
                    textColor: "white",
                    color: 'gold',
                    selected: true,
                }
    });
        return dates;
    }
```